# Converting Dates to "YYYY" format in Power Bi

Tags: datetime, powerbi, data-analysis

the dates in this data are in number format so i can date back to previous year to calculate for say "% growth".
I tried using `DateAdd() of BI`  and `Parralleldate()` but the dates are not in the right format.
Please who can help me sort out this problem

I have got the years and number of internet users for each country. Trying to calculate for a "% growth" of the internet users i need to date back to previous year using `dateadd()` or `parralleldate()` functions of BI.
To solve this, I went back to the original doc at Excel and formatted the dates from TEXT format to DATES "yyyy" format. Uploaded the new DOC and yet unable to get the desired result.
BI formular looks

```
Calculate(sumx( [USA],USA[no.internet users], 
Paralleldate(USA[Year],-1, YEAR))
```

Comment: For starters, where's your Calendar table??

CALCULATE(
              SUMX( 'USA', [no.internet users]), 
SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DimDate[Date])
)

Comment: Thank you for the input. My data set does not have a date/calender table. Year is the only date value provided for this data set to determine internet users by each country . for context; the data set has 8,800+ rows ( accounting for every country, by year since 1980-2020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For date functions (dateadd, Parallelperiod, Previousyear) to work you will need a Calender table in your data model.

As you only have a year field, add a calculated column to create a date field like `Date = DATE('USA'[Year],1,1)` and then create a Calender table using `Calendar = CALENDAR(FIRSTDATE('USA'[Date]),LASTDATE('USA'[Date]))` and create a relationship between both the tables.

Now you can use `CALCULATE([Sum], PARALLELPERIOD(Cal[Date],-1,YEAR))` to get Previous year numbers.

Comment: Thanks Hatim for this tip. I sure will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't have a Calendar table you can create a measure like this:

```
Prev Year Total = CALCULATE ( [Total Amount],FILTER(ALL('FactTableName'),[Year] = MAX([Year])-1)
)
```

Basically, I'm getting current year (MAX([Year]) only returns one value in this context), and then subtracting one from it. Then the measure is basically adjusting the evaluation context for the expression back one year.

if you had more than just years, I would definitely suggest a Calendar table. (Lots of the date-related functions in DAX assume you have a separate calendar table, so keep that in mind if you get stuck.)

Comment: I very much appreciate your help Pieter. I will sure keep your words in mind